# How would you convert a link to a media item to the file URL in a menu?

Tags: 8, files

I would like to be able to link to media in a Drupal menu and have the link converted to a file url.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution, where you add the link like this: '/media/1234'

And then add this code:

```
function mymodule_link_alter(&$variables) {
  $url = $variables['url'];

  if (!$url->isRouted() && $uri = $variables['url']->getUri()) {
    preg_match('/base\:media\/(\d+)/', $variables['url']->getUri(), $match);
    if (!empty($match) && !empty($match[1])) {
      $media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load($match[1]);
      if (!empty($media) && $media->bundle() === 'document') {
        if ($file = $media->field_media_file->entity) {
          $variables['url'] = Url::fromUri(file_create_url($file->getFileUri()), $url->getOptions());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hardcoded the source field.  You could make it more generic if you like.